# Python fastest way to find values in big data

Tags: python, performance

I have a huge database with rows structured by the fields "date, ad, site, impressions, clicks"

I got all of them via python using:

```
cursor.execute(select * from dabase)
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

From all this data, I need to sample only the rows that happened in a certain time an ad when printed in certain site has lead to an amount of clicks bigger than zero, so for instance:

row(1) : (t1, ad1, site1) -> clicks = 1 (t is time)

row(2) : (t2, ad1, site1) -> clicks = 0

So the ad1 and site1 at point t1 had clicks > 0 and therefore **all points in data containing ad1 and site1 must be taken and put into another list**, which I called final_list that would contain row(1) and row(2) (row(2) has 0 clicks, but since in time t1 ad1 and site1 had clicks > 0, so this row must be taken as well)

When I tried making it via MySQL Workbench it took so long that I got the error message "Lost Connection to Database". I think it happens because the table has almost 40 million rows, even though I´ve seem people working with much bigger amounts of data here MySQL is not being able to handle it, that´s why I used python (in fact, to get the rows with clicks > 0 it took a few seconds in python whereas it took more than 10 minutes via MySQL, I´m not sure precisely how long it was)

What I did then was to first select points ad and site with clicks > 0:

```
points = [(row[1], row[2]) for row in data if row[4]]
points = list(set(points))
dic = {}
for element in points:
    dic[element] = 1
```

This code took just a few seconds to run. Having a dictionary with the wanted points I began to insert data into the final_list:

```
final_list = []
for row in data:
    try:
        if dic[(row[1], row[2])] == 1: final_list.append(row)
    except: continue
```

But it´s taking too long and I´ve been trying to figure out a way to make it go faster. Is it possible?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do this in the query?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not doing it on the database? I mean, within query? Databases are optimized to work faster for these kind of operations.

Comment: Do you know about SQL's `where` clause? Right now you might as well not be using a database at all; play to its strengths

Comment: I just want to play devils advocate against the commentors for a second, and give the OP the benefit of the doubt that maybe he just did a one-off dump of data from an sql server that he doesnt normally have direct production access to. And now maybe he wants to do various processing and filtering of this data. Not saying I am correct, but we still dont know the situation. So comments and answers assuming sql is the solution are still only speculations. .

Comment: In that case the best (most elegant, fastest?) way of doing this would probably be to re-import it into an `sqlite3` database and then use SQL. There's no better way to query data than to use a language (SQL) that was designed to do it.

Comment: Ops I forgot to mention more information about the database, sorry for that. I´ll reedit the question

Comment: Hi Will, can you dump the database schema of the table with the sql: `show create table TABLENAME`. MySQL can certainly deal with the size of data you're talking about it is likely something to do with the datatypes used or an issue with indexing (any extra info will help, such as details of the indexes in place or putting an `explain` in front of your query with `count > 0`)

Comment: Ok I stand corrected in my support for the OP. Its obviously either a lack of knowledge of SQL, or a missing index on the "clicks" field. There is no reason the query on 40 million rows should take over 10 minutes. Thats a really simple query. Its probably just having to do a full table scan with every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the comments have asked why you aren't able to just do this in the database, which I wonder as well... but as for at least addressing your code, you probably don't need a bunch of steps in the middle such as converting to list -> set -> list -> dictionary. I'm sure the list append()'s are killing you, as well as the for loops.

What about this?

```
points = set((row[1], row[2]) for row in data if row[4])
final_list = [d for d in data if (d[1], d[2]) in points]
```

You could even see if this is faster to get your point set:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import ifilter

points = set(ifilter(itemgetter(4), data))
getter = itemgetter(1,2)
final_list = [d for d in data if getter(d) in points]
```

*My answer gives your question the benefit of the doubt that you have no option for doing this regularily from sql with a better sql query*

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much for the help jdi! I tried to make as you did but with one difference: I´ve transformed the set 'points' into a list, so the code "final_list = [d for d in data if (d[1], d[2]) in points]" was taking tooo long (still not sure why), but doing so having points as a set took less than a second...! Tnx!

Comment: Set is faster because it uses hashes to store the items and to do the test of whether one memeber is in the set. It does not have to scan the whole collection every time. It know instantly if the item is in it

Answer (score -1):

You are reinventing the wheel.

Use a `WHERE` clause on your `SELECT` query to filter the results of your query.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dabase WHERE clicks > 0")
```

This is faster because:

- The database is heavily optimised to make `SELECT ... WHERE` very fast. It will be much, much faster than literally *any* method you use to replicate a `WHERE` clause in Python.
- Less data needs to be moved between the SQL server and you (important if your SQL server is on a network.) Instead of having the SQL server send you *all* the data, most of which you're going to throw away, just have the SQL server send you the filtered data you actually want.